# Distributed Cubes in the same JVM

Tags: activepivot

A quick question on distributed cubes.  I've seen them suggested as the solution to several questions here ([Such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947890/2224622)) and I'm curious if it's possible to run two or more polymorphic distributed cubes within the same JVM - so a single ActivePivot application instance with two or more distributed cubes.  It's not clear looking at the documentation if this is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely possible as 2 cubes in the same JVM could communicate through the local machine network. This can be optimized further by using the LOCAL_MESSENGER, which will do less Serialization, but more clones.

```
    <distributedActivePivot>
        <Id>DistributedCubeName</Id>
        <clusterId>ClusterId</clusterId>
        <distributionType>POLYMORPHIC</distributionType>
        <underlyingPivotId>CubeName</underlyingPivotId>
        <properties>
            <!-- <entry key="distributedMessengerKey" value="JGROUPS_MESSENGER" /> -->
            <entry key="distributedMessengerKey" value="LOCAL_MESSENGER" />
        </properties>
    </distributedActivePivot>
```